# filling a pd data frame with lists as columns looping through list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
index_names = ['1c', '1s', '2c', '2s', '2s', '3c', '3s', '4c', '4s']

individual_atom_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Q0', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], index=index_names)
```

which returns the following:

```
     Q0   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4
1c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1s  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2s  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2s  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3s  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4s  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

as expected. The data that fills this data frame are lists contained within a list, whereby each list length varies according to a (2x + 1) rule. Here is an example of the lists:

```
my_list = [[-1.064525],
 [-4e-06, -0.105246, 0.036201],
 [0.340138, -6e-06, -2e-06, -0.454872, 0.383145],
 [4e-06, -0.208369, -0.482417, -4e-06, 3e-06, -0.105177, -0.097678],
 [0.047612,
  3.5e-05,
  5e-06,
  0.734665,
  0.979878,
  -2.9e-05,
  1.5e-05,
  0.45498,
  -0.005097]]
```

Each list will occupy a column of this data frame relating to the index of that list, for example:

-1.064525: Q0-1c (because -1.064525 is my_list[0][0] so it occupies Q0)

-4e-06: Q1-1c, -0.105246: Q1-1s, 0.036201: Q1-2c

and so on until the top right diagonal of the data frame is full of the my_list values, and the bottom left diagonal is left with NaN.

I need to iterate through my_list and fill the columns of the data frame (the reason for this is because this isn't the only list of lists, in fact there are many list of lists are contained in a dictionary, see ahead).

```
dictionary =  {'H5': [[0.355421],
  [-0.013164, -0.012894, 0.012746],
  [0.011902, 0.004148, 0.00579, -0.022556, 0.017715],
  [-0.007411, 0.015751, 0.003681, -0.0048, -0.020631, -0.004436, -0.002779],
  [-0.012934,
   -0.00844,
   -0.013543,
   0.003076,
   0.00371,
   -0.008476,
   -0.008116,
   -0.001628,
   0.006953]],
 'N1': [[-1.064525],
  [-4e-06, -0.105246, 0.036201],
  [0.340138, -6e-06, -2e-06, -0.454872, 0.383145],
  [4e-06, -0.208369, -0.482417, -4e-06, 3e-06, -0.105177, -0.097678],
  [0.047612,
   3.5e-05,
   5e-06,
   0.734665,
   0.979878,
   -2.9e-05,
   1.5e-05,
   0.45498,
   -0.005097]]}
```

I have tried this, but I'm quite new to data frames and I would highly appreciate some help in how to fill the data frame with the content of my_list. This is what I've tried:

```
for kk in dictionary:

    # define dataframe
    individual_atom_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Q0', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], index=index_names)

    # jj is a loop over Q0, Q1, Q2....
    for idx, val in enumerate(individual_atom_df):
        individual_atom_df[val].append(dictionary[kk][idx])
```

Each data frame generated for each dictionary element will be outputted to a .json file using the following (which will be put at the end of the loop):

```
coord_string = df.to_string().splitlines()

coord_data = {

    'File origin': file_directory,
    'Error list': error_array,
    'Data': coord_string

}

with open("file_name.json", "w") as coord_json:
    json.dump(file_name, coord_json, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, in your outer loop you are overwriting your dataframe with every iteration.  You need to save it in some fashion, maybe in a dictionary defined outside the loop.  That said, what you are doing in the loop could be done with 
something like the following:

```
# data
l1 = [np.random.rand()]
l2 = [np.random.rand() for i in range(3)]
l3 = [np.random.rand() for i in range(5)]
ll = [l1, l2, l3]

# find max length
maxlen = max(len(i) for i in ll)

# extend shorter arrays by filling with NaN
for col in ll:
    col.extend((maxlen-len(col)) * [np.nan])

# convert to array
arr = np.asarray(ll).T

df = pd.DataFrame(
    arr,
    columns=[f'Q{i}' for i in range(1,4)],
    index=['1c', '1s', '2c', '2s', '2s']
    )
```

Does this help?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify your point regarding reinitialising the data frame in each iteration of the loop. Good idea, it doesn't answer the question but I'll give it go.

Comment: Could you clarify how my answer doesn't answer your question? You asked how to fill the dataframe, given the irregular shape of your data.  I have shown how to reasonably get the data into a regular shape, and subsequently used it to create a dataframe.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I didn't inspect your answer well enough, and I was wrong. This is perfect, so my apologies and thank you very much - accepted as the answer now.